# SQLAlchemy issue with multiple identity insert and Date column

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm encountering an odd issue where I get an 'Invalid character value for cast specification' error when I'm trying to insert rows containing Date types. I narrowed down the conditions that cause the issue to arise and it seems to happen exclusively when all of these factors are combined:

1. iserrting into an autoincrement PK id column with identity_insert AND
2. inserting into a Date column AND
3. there are multiple objects added to the session when I commit (fast_executemany=True)

Here I demonstrate the issue:

```
class TestDate(Model):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'test'}
    __tablename__ = 'TestDate'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)


class TestString(Model):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'test'}
    __tablename__ = 'TestString'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    string = Column(String, nullable=False)


db.session.add(TestDate(id=1, date='01/01/2021'))
db.session.commit()
# no issue

db.session.add(TestDate(date='01/01/2021'))
db.session.add(TestDate(date='01/01/2021'))
db.session.commit()
# no issue

db.session.add(TestString(id=1, string='01/01/2021'))
db.session.add(TestString(id=2, string='01/01/2021'))
db.session.commit()
# no issue

db.session.add(TestDate(id=4, date='01/01/2021'))
db.session.add(TestDate(id=5, date='01/01/2021'))
db.session.commit()
# error!
```

Here is the output of the above code using SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True:

```
2021-02-17 00:51:14,102 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-02-17 00:51:14,108 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestDate] ON
2021-02-17 00:51:14,109 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-02-17 00:51:14,112 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO test.[TestDate] (id, date) VALUES (?, ?)
2021-02-17 00:51:14,112 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1, '01/01/2021')
2021-02-17 00:51:14,120 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestDate] OFF
2021-02-17 00:51:14,121 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-02-17 00:51:14,126 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT

2021-02-17 00:51:15,471 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-02-17 00:51:15,476 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO test.[TestDate] (date) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?)
2021-02-17 00:51:15,477 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('01/01/2021',)
2021-02-17 00:51:15,486 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO test.[TestDate] (date) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?)
2021-02-17 00:51:15,487 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('01/01/2021',)
2021-02-17 00:51:15,493 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT

2021-02-17 00:51:16,880 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-02-17 00:51:16,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestString] ON
2021-02-17 00:51:16,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-02-17 00:51:16,891 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO test.[TestString] (id, string) VALUES (?, ?)
2021-02-17 00:51:16,891 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ((1, '01/01/2021'), (2, '01/01/2021'))
2021-02-17 00:51:16,898 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestString] OFF
2021-02-17 00:51:16,899 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-02-17 00:51:16,906 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT

2021-02-17 00:51:20,895 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-02-17 00:51:20,902 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestDate] ON
2021-02-17 00:51:20,902 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-02-17 00:51:20,905 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO test.[TestDate] (id, date) VALUES (?, ?)
2021-02-17 00:51:20,905 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ((4, '01/01/2021'), (5, '01/01/2021'))
2021-02-17 00:51:20,914 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
 [snip]
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')
```

The reason I want use identity_insert is so that I can quickly drop all tables and create all tables and then populate tables to an initial state loaded from local .tsv or .json files that have all the rows of the initial state of the database, for quick testing and prototyping. If I don't provide the ids, then I don't think I reap the speed advantages of fast_executemany.

It appears that the error is avoided in the second case above because without providing the id, SQLAlchemy is forced to insert each entry on its own line (which defeats fast_executemany).

What's more odd is that if I take the raw sqlalchemy output from the failing case, fix up the syntax, and run it directly in SQL Server Management studio, it works just fine. So, what is going on?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestDate] ON
INSERT INTO test.[TestDate]
    (id, date)
VALUES 
    (4, '01/01/2021'),
    (5, '01/01/2021')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.[TestDate] OFF
-- (2 rows affected)
```

The dialect is mssql: 'mssql+pyodbc:///?DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
SQLAlchemy 1.3.22

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It appears that when fast_executemany is used, the allowable formats of string literals for Date and DateTime columns is very strict, because of an implementation detail which is probably necessary for the performance improvements.

The exact string formats required are listed at this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements?view=sql-server-2017